# ExecutorService analog in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, concurrency, kotlin-coroutines, executorservice

I have a piece of Java code that uses ExecutorService. I need to convert this code to Kotlin using coroutines. I tried using GlobalScope.launch() which did work but very differently. In Java code there is EXECUTOR_SERVICE.shutdown() and EXECUTOR_SERVICE.awaitTermination to determine when all the tasks are completed. What would be the closest implementation to this in Kotlin?

Java code:

```
final ExecutorService EXECUTOR_SERVICE =
                Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
for (int d = MIN_DEPTH; d <= maxDepth; d += 2) {
            final int depth = d;
            EXECUTOR_SERVICE.execute(() -> {
                int check = 0;

                final int iterations = 1 << (maxDepth - depth + MIN_DEPTH);
                for (int i = 1; i <= iterations; ++i) {
                    final TreeNode treeNode1 = bottomUpTree(depth);
                    check += treeNode1.itemCheck();
                }
                results[(depth - MIN_DEPTH) / 2] =
                        iterations + "\t trees of depth " + depth + "\t check: " + check;
            });
        }
EXECUTOR_SERVICE.shutdown();
EXECUTOR_SERVICE.awaitTermination(120L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: The question seems to be implying that Java's ExecutorService is not available in Kotlin. While the questioner may not have intended that, it may be worth underlining for posterity that Kotlin/JVM has access to all Java platform classes and all Java libraries, just like in Java.

Comment: @gidds Not exactly, I wonder what would be the Kotlin idiomatic way to implement this

Comment: If you're using IntelliJ, write your Java code, then tell the IDE to convert it into Kotlin. It doesn't always come up with neat, idiomatic Kotlin (in fact, sometimes it doesn't even come up with _compilable_ code…) but it's usually a very good place to start from.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin does not tie thread pools to work completion, but your solution was already an accurate translation.  You do not need to do anything special to wait for the tasks to complete; this is done automatically by `launch` and by every coroutine builder method as a result of [structured concurrency](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html).

I would write this as

```kotlin
val result : List<Int> = runBlocking {
  // you can specify a thread pool, but it looks like you should really use the default one
  (MIN_DEPTH..maxDepth step 2).map { depth ->
    async {
      val check = 0
      val iterations = 1 shl (maxDepth - depth + MIN_DEPTH)
      for (i in 0 until iterations) {
        check += bottomUpTree(depth).itemCheck()
      }
      check
    }
   }.awaitAll()
}
```